# Методы оценки качества сжатия сигнала

Tags: цос, dsp

Требуется оценить качество сжатия сигнала, а именно, имеется не сжатый .wav файл с определенным сигналом, необходимо произвести его сжатия с использование разных кодаков и провести оценку сжатия. И я как раз не могу понять, с чем мне сравнивать, у меня же нет эталонного сжатого сигнала на основе которого я бы мог провести анализ. Ведь после сжатия, количество данных уменьшится и сравнить к примеру спектрограммы будет невозможно или я ошибаюсь?

За ранее большое спасибо за ответы и критику!!!

Comment: Как раз спектры и можно и нужно сравнивать.